# how to create PDF from Wiris editor?

Tags: javascript, java, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF from [WIRIS editor](http://www.wiris.com/editor/demo/en/), which is an editor for math equations,

I think it is possible to get PDF from WIRIS but I dont know how to do that using the [Java API](http://www.wiris.com/editor/docs/servicesapis) or in any other way

Sorry I am new to JAVA so some body suggest a way to get PDF from WIRIS

Thanks

Comment: java or javascript? or is it really both?

Comment: it may be in any way, to get PDF from WIRIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, it is only possible to generate a PDF using a Web service or using the Java/C# API. To create a PDF using a Web call, follow the instructions from http://www.wiris.com/en/editor/docs/servicesapis . For example, http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render?mml=%3Cmath%3E%3Cmn%3E2%3C/mn%3E%3Cmo%3E-%3C/mo%3E%3Cmi%3Ex%3C/mi%3E%3C/math%3E&format=pdf

To use the Java/C# API, you will need to contact the support team of WIRIS.

Keep in mind that WIRIS is a comercial product and you might need a license if you put your product under production.